# Which Ethereum clients/wallets support the ICAP?

Tags: clients, addresses, icap

The [ICAP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol) is a method of representing an Ethereum address with a built-in checksum and in a way that is compliant with most bank software due to compliance with the [International Bank Account Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) (IBAN) format.  But many block explorers and other tools are still using the raw hexadecimal representation for Ethereum addresses.  Which Ethereum clients/wallets/apps actually support the ICAP?

Answer (score 2):

Found [ethereumjs-icap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-icap)

> Utilities for handling ICAP (Ethereum in IBAN) encoding

**API Says**

- `fromAddress(address, print, nonstd)` - try encoding an address into an IBAN
- `fromAsset(asset, print)` - try encoding an asset description into an IBAN
- `toAddress(iban)` - try decoding an IBAN into an address description
- `toAsset(iban)` - try decoding an IBAN into an asset description
- `encode(address/asset)` - encode an address or an asset description into an IBAN
- `decode(iban)` - decode an IBAN into an address or asset description
- `encodeBBAN(address/asset)` - encode an address or an asset description into a BBAN
- `decodeBBAN(bban)` - decode a BBAN into an address or asset description

**Status of Ethereum Wallet 0.3.8 (Beta 5)**

> Not yet implemented [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/40hzr9/ethereum_wallet_038_beta_5_released/cyub81o)

Comment: What about Geth and Aleth?

Answer (score 1):

Geth does not support ICAP yet. It's planned for the 1.4.1 release which are scheduled sometime after the Homestead release.

Eth does support ICAP, it's build in for a while now, but I never heard of anyone actually using it. I would recommend using it with care.

Comment: Small corrections on Geth. Homestead is 1.3.4, and will roll out with only the consensus changes. We don't want feature in there so if something goes wrong, we know where to look and fix. We'll release 1.4 maybe a week after homestead, which will roll out all the features worked on over the last months. ICAP is planned for 1.4.1 only, as we're freezing 1.4 and a new addressing scheme isn't so simple as to do a quick merge.

Comment: @PéterSzilágyi so what's the status now?

Comment: I think it's safe to say ICAP is abandoned.