# What is the difference between ICAP and HEX addresses?

Tags: mining, addresses, exchanges, icap

I've read what Kraken have mentioned in the [difference guide](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/207446777-Which-ETH-deposit-option-should-I-choose-Hex-or-ICAP-) but I haven't understood it well.

I plan to mine ethereum. What fits better for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly, ICAP addresses are safer to use, since they have a checksum which provides protection against mistyping an address.  But ICAP adoption isn't as widespread currently.  For mining you can use either, since a HEX address, when needed, can always be obtained from an ICAP address.

More information:

[What is an ICAP address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/what-is-an-icap-address)

[Why don't Ethereum addresses have checksums?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/267/why-dont-ethereum-addresses-have-checksums)

See also questions tagged with [address](/questions/tagged/address) and [icap](/questions/tagged/icap).

Comment: Is it even possible to send ETH to an ICAP address using geth or eth, yet?

Comment: @5chdn Answered by you in this question, and also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/330/which-ethereum-clients-wallets-support-the-icap  Maybe we can link your 2 answers better ;)

Answer (score 3):

Kraken sais:

> ICAP is the best option for wallets that support it.

So the direct answer to your question is a list of clients which support it:

- `eth` seems to support ICAP but it's integration looks experimental. I would **use hex instead**.
- `geth` **does not support ICAP**. Use HEX instead. Basic ICAP support is planned for future releases, maybe [starting at version 1.4.x](https://twitter.com/jeffehh/status/695761551165419520).
- `mist` **does not support ICAP**. Use HEX instead. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/40hzr9/ethereum_wallet_038_beta_5_released/cyub81o).
- `ethereum-js` [seems to support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-icap) ICAP, but I guess you are not using a JavaScript client.

TL;DR use HEX for now.